# Behat, AJAX functionality support required

Tags: php, ajax, automated-tests, behat, gherkin

So I am doing a few behat tests on a website. so far so good until I encountered on an AJAX functionality (i.e. a click to a link or a button does not change or refresh the page but new content is added or removed from the page it was already on).

This has caused some trouble to me as JS was not supportive of my behat tests. I am not sure what drivers to add in order to get the AJAX functionality working on Behat. I believe my Behat works on a headless browser as of now. not sure how i have to go about with this in order to deal with such ajax functionality. can someone help me out with this?

So my behat.yml would be this

```
default:
  suites:
    default:
      path: %paths.base%/features/bootstrap
      contexts: 
        - FeatureContext
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      base_url: http://somethingimportant.prod.com/
      sessions:
        default:
          goutte: ~
```

the feature file i want to test is this

```
Scenario: Manage the favourites on the favourites page
Given I am on homepage
When I will login as globaladmin
Then I click "My account"
Then I click "Favourites"
Then I click "Manage" //After this click is where the AJAX comes into play
Then I wait 2 seconds
Then I should see "Save Order"
```

This is my featurecontext.php

```
<?php

use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\PyStringNode;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\TableNode;
use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;

/**
 * Defines application features from the specific context.
 */
class FeatureContext extends MinkContext implements Context
{
    **
    * @Then /^I wait (\d+) seconds$/
    */
    public function iWaitSeconds($time) 
    {
        $this->getSession()->wait($time * 1000);
    }
}
```

This is the error I get

```
Feature: This feature will test the Favourites page

  Scenario: Manage the favourites on the favourites page # features/favourites.feature:3
    Given I am on homepage                               # FeatureContext::iAmOnHomepage()
    When I will login as globaladmin                     # FeatureContext::iWillLoginAsGlobaladmin()
    Then I click "My account"                            # FeatureContext::assertClick()
    Then I click "Favourites"                            # FeatureContext::assertClick()
    Then I click "Manage"                                # FeatureContext::assertClick()
    Then I wait 2 seconds                                # FeatureContext::iWaitSeconds()
      JS is not supported by Behat\Mink\Driver\GoutteDriver (Behat\Mink\Exception\UnsupportedDriverActionException)
    Then I should see "Hey"
```

any help is appreciated. thank you in advance people of the world :)

Comment: For Ajax or anything involving JS you need to use Selenium, you can't use a headless browser.

Comment: Thank you. Also one more question was while using selenium, can we also make the tests run by opening the browser and letting us see what goes on ?

Comment: Yes you can, I did it some time ago.

Comment: Do you have something that you can share, like the behat.yml file and the featurecontext file? I am trying various type of installations but always running into some error. would be really helpful if i got something that is proven to work

Comment: Check this repo https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius, it’s probably the best example on how to use Behat